# How to use PHP imap_search() by message ID

Tags: php, imap

Trying to use PHP imap_search to find out if a given message is already in a mailbox (working on an IMAP sync / migration tool).

I know my test message is there:

```
Connected to imap.example.com
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE 
STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Welcome to mofoMail.
a1 LOGIN {username} {password}
a1 OK [snip] Logged in
a2 examine INBOX
a2 OK [READ-ONLY] Select completed.
a3 SEARCH HEADER Message-ID <001a11490a9ecd38280569bfcddf@google.com>
* SEARCH 1 11 19 21 25 35 39 48 54
a3 OK Search completed (0.402 secs).
```

Now in the migration script (modifying [php_imap_sync](https://github.com/vcorbacho/php_imap_sync)), I have this working, it just copies all the messages from source to destination, so the connection and so forth is working... but now I want to modify it so if the job is interrupted or has to be done in stages, it won't recopy messages that have already been migrated over, so trying to check if the message-ID is already there...

```
$array_mailbox[ $dst ] = imap_open( '{' . ${$dst}['server'] . ':' . ${$dst}['port'] . ${$dst}['str_connection']  . '}INBOX', ${$dst}['username'], ${$dst}['password']);
// stuff skipped
// getting header of current message from source mailbox 
$header = imap_headerinfo($array_mailbox[ 'origin' ], $key+1);


$messageHeader = imap_fetchheader($array_mailbox['origin'], $key+1);
$msgHeader = imap_rfc822_parse_headers($messageHeader);
// above works as expected, my message-ID, same from example is in
//  $msgHeader->message_id

// so why doesn't the following work?
 $search_str = sprintf("HEADER Message-ID %s", $msgHeader->message_id);
 $test = imap_search($array_mailbox['target'], $search_str);

 echo "TESTING"; print_r($test);
 if($test) {
       printf("Already ported %s\n", $msgHeader->message_id);
       next;
  }
```

$test is always false. Even when I'm hitting the same message-id as my telnet test above.

I'm obviously missing something about imap_search() but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Use UIDs, they are maintained by the server, guaranteed to be unique (with conditions) and strictly increase (if the folder is no recreated)

Comment: Would the UID be the same across servers tho?

Comment: No;  just track up to what UID you have copied for any given folder.  When copying a message, when you get the OK on the destination server, the message should be copied and you mark the source UID as copied.  Message-IDs are unreliable because they are sender generated.  I can easily break your script by sending you different messages with the same Message-ID.